# dimensions change when you use zoom css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to add zooming system manually to my electron app because there is no zooming in it. so I added it and it didn't work as expected. when I zoom with my browser the offsets are working fine but when I add zoom in the css
every thing has offsets.

**example:** I have a div that has a button and when I click it has to move to the mouse position. It works fine but when you zoom in every thing falls apart.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="div1" class="div">
        <button id="btn">follow clicks</button>
    </div>

    <button onclick="zoom()">zoom</button>
    <script>
        var div1 = document.querySelector("#div1")
        var btn = document.querySelector("#btn")
        var body = document.querySelector("body")
        var curzoom = 100
        function zoom() {
            curzoom += 10
            body.style.zoom = curzoom + "%"
        }
        div1.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect()
            btn.style.top = e.clientY - rect.top
            btn.style.left = e.clientX - rect.left
            /*I don't know why style.top and left doesn't  
            work on code snippet. it works on my browser
            */
        })
    </script>
    <style>
        .div {
            width: 700px;
            height: 500px;
        }

        #div1 {
            background-color: #ff0000;
            position: relative;
        }

        #btn {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        body {
            zoom: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</body>

</html>
```

in this code, when you click the zoom button and then select the div the button has a huge offset and the more you zoom, the worse it gets...

Answer (score 0):

When you click the zoom button, everything is multiplied by `curzoom` variable.
You have to subtract the zoomed amount of pixels on button's position.

```
 btn.style.top = e.clientY - rect.top - (e.clientY - rect.top) * ((curzoom - 100) / 100);
 btn.style.left = e.clientX - rect.left - (e.clientX - rect.left) * ((curzoom - 100) / 100);
```

Comment: that makes it way better, but still when you zoom more, it gets worse